# How to define a fraction of tt font variables?

Tags: math-mode, typewriter

I am trying to define something like `$\frac\mathtt{A\_B}\mathtt{C\_D}$` to get a fraction of two typewriter-font variables (inline math preferred), but I keep getting errors such as

> "missing } inserted"

and the result is definitely wrong.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$\frac{\mathtt{A_B}}{\mathtt{C_D}}$` ... you need some extra braces.

Comment: Even when you recall the proper syntax, it is easy to forget braces when typing.  Often, when doing something complicated, I will type in empty braces for the arguments and later fill them in.  Thus, here I might type `\frac{}{}`, and then go in and fill in `\frac{\mathtt{}}{\mathtt{}}`.  Finally, I would insert `A\_B` and `C\_D` as the final step.  It helps to avoid getting confused.

Comment: Surprisingly, it helped! I used to type things such as \frac 1 2, and assumed a LaTeX command would be also treated as a single element, but I guess there is more to it.

Comment: There are some macros that if you omit the braces, it will take the next [single] token as the argument.  And there are other macros where it will protest the omission of braces.  Unless you know that a macro is happy with the braces omitted, it is safer to retain them by way of habit.

Comment: Whoever maintains that `\frac 1 2` is good input should look at this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `\frac` can't know where the numerator ends and the denominator begins nor when the denominator ends, unless you tell it *precisely*.

The macro `\frac` has two arguments, so its syntax is

```
\frac{<numerator>}{<denominator>}
```

and it's better to keep this in mind.

It's true that `\mathtt` needs an argument, so it's clear to a human reader what the numerator and denominator should be in

```
\frac\mathtt{A\_B}\mathtt{C\_D}
```

However, TeX is a computer program, not a human being, and it need precise instructions.

Speaking generally, macros are processed from left to right, so what TeX sees is `\frac` and it knows it should receive two arguments.

The rule how an argument is determined, when looked for is quite simple:

1. spaces are ignored until finding something which is not a space;
2. if the next token is a `{`, the argument is whatever goes from `{` up to the matching `}`;
3. otherwise the next token is the argument.

When rule 2 is used, the braces are stripped off after the argument has been determined.

It's by rules 1 and 3 that an input such as `\frac 1 2` leads to a properly formatted fraction. In fact, TeX sees `1` and determines it's the first argument to `\frac`, then it ignores the space and determnes that `2` is the second argument.

Similarly, with your input, `\mathtt` is determined to be the first argument and `{A\_B}` is the second one! So your input is completely equivalent to

```
\frac{\mathtt}{A\_B}\mathtt{C\_D}
```

which will lead to a malformed numerator and so to weird error messages.

Conversely, with

```
\frac{\mathtt{A\_B}}{\mathtt{C\_D}}
```

the fraction will be typeset correctly.

Moral of the story: ***always*** use braces around arguments. When you're an experienced TeX user, you may know when it's safe to omit the braces. But be careful:

```
\frac 11 2
```

will possibly surprise you! Read again rules 1 to 3 and you'll discover that typing

```
\frac{11}{2}
```

is the best strategy. And `\frac{1}{2}` too.

Comment: missed a pair.  fixed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was answering while sipping a good glass of wine on the train, so I got distracted. `;-)`